# How to disable log4j logging in Http Client 4.1 to log to FileAppender

Tags: java, log4j, httpclient

Here is my log4j configuration for a HTTP client:

```
log4j.appender.HTTPCLIENT_APPDR=com.xxx.log.FileAppender
log4j.appender.HTTPCLIENT_APPDR.File=${user.dir}/log/access.log
log4j.appender.HTTPCLIENT_APPDR.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HTTPCLIENT_APPDR_APPDR.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss SSS}ms %-5p [%t] - %m%n
log4j.appender.HTTPCLIENT_APPDR.MaxFileSize=20000KB
log4j.appender.HTTPCLIENT_APPDR.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=DEBUG,HTTPCLIENT_APPDR
```

I would like it to turn off the `httpclient` logging from the CODE depending on the environment I am in (I know how to disable it from the log4j.properties).

I tried inserting these lines:

```
+    System.setProperty("log4j.logger.org.apache.http", "ERROR");
```

or

```
+    Logger.getLogger("log4j.logger.org.apache.http").setLevel(Level.off)
```

in the start of my application but it does not work.

1. Can I access the log4j properties from the System class?
2. When I look at the `Logger.getLogger("log4j.logger.org.apache.http")` the level is null? Should it not be DEBUG?

What worked finally,

```
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
```

I was not using the right key.

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What worked finally,
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
I was not using the right key.

Comment: Worked for me. I put it at the code, redeployed and everything fine. Thanks for helping me to make my log readable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a log4j.properties file, add this line

`log4j.logger.org.apache.http=WARN`

This is only tested in Apache HttpClient 4