# How to not log Http logs using log4j in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, logging, log4j

i am using mavn project and selenium with log4j logging. The configuration of log4j is

> log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, file log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
>   log4j.logger.httpclient=WARN
>   log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.file.File=${log}/log_text.log
>   log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
>   log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
>   log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
>   %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

But in my log file, I'm getting logs of HTTP logs alongwith log command whichever i have given in my code. Please help me on to get only my logs or How to avoid logging Http logs in Selenium.

Http logs I'm getting in log file as follows

> http-outgoing-8 << "Content-Length:102[\r][\n]" http-outgoing-8 <<
>   "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]" http-outgoing-8
>   << "Connection:close[\r][\n]" http-outgoing-8 << "[\r][\n]"
>   http-outgoing-8 <<
>   "{"sessionId":"50963105f111f728f5901c2a44af28de","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.8072388418087275-2"}}"
>   http-outgoing-8 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Log4j v1.2.17

Comment: Check this thread, may be useful:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging)
or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935923/how-to-disable-log4j-logging-in-http-client-4-1-to-log-to-fileappender)

Comment: Thanks for the link.. Its fine now...